# Is there a way to set a stylesheet’s priority higher than !important?

Tags: css, wordpress

**I know I should not really ask this question, but before I get down voted to oblivion hear me out … I try to make the best out of a really bad situation:**

My client has bought a WordPress theme and hired me to customize some parts of it. The bought theme is a a child theme and is a coding horror …
The theme’s stylesheet, tries to overwrite some styles from the woocommerce plugin, while the woocommerce stylesheet is loaded after the theme’s stylesheet. To do so it uses a crapload of `!important` declarations. I can not really fix any of this without breaking the theme update function.

So here is my plan: I want to add another stylesheet at the end, which overwrites all the mess, that has been done before. But simply putting it there would not overwrite all the `!important` declarations from the stylesheets before. So I was wondering if there is a way to prioritize my stylesheet above all the mess from before.

Any way to up my priority above the `!important` declarations are also appreciated!

Comment: Only `inline !important` can overwrite !important style rules defined elsewhere. Even !important placed afterwards can overwrite them. But both the options would make your situation messier.

Comment: As far as I know, no. I hate using `!important`, and definitely hate seeing it throughout a CSS file (I know you didn't write the CSS). I would recommend going through the file and riding yourself of these (yes, it will take time). It's going to break it, as you said, but if you rearrange the styles, it'll come out. I would stay away from inline styles, that's just bad practice, same as using `!important` in the first place

Comment: @RobScott Yeah, I thought about that, but the client wants to have unrestricted admin access to the page. If he decides to update the theme, all those changes will be deleted and my css breaks completely …

Comment: @Moob answer is the only way. If you can't get priority to your css new sheet, and don't want to check parent f the class for more specifi declaration you could overwrite the important adding `body` before the class: body .class {whatever !important}

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I feared that … damn the `!important` declaration! :/

Comment: Instead of working around this problem, have you check whether you could maybe change the order in which the stylesheets are loaded? If so, load them the *correct* way, and use a simple search/replace to get rid if the `!important` declarations. Even with an update, this process should be repeatable without too much hassle.

Comment: @Yoshi I thought about that, but I will not maintain the website. It might be easy fix the stylesheet order and do a search and replace, if you have some coding knowledge. But since my client does not have any, he would need someone to do the work for him after each update.

Comment: Ok, then one last possibility would be, provided the site is not a high-frequency one, to load the stylesheet through a php-file. This way you could remove the declarations *on-the-fly*.

Comment: @Yoshi You mean inlining the css with `<style>`  after editing it via php? That could work if I find a way to do the same thing with the stylesheet order. Sadly there is no way I know of to create a grand-child theme, but I will look into it. Maybe this would be an alternative …

Comment: Well not necessarily inlining, but in general yes. For example, point the <link> to some php file. This php file in turn loads the problematic stylesheet and removes the important declarations. Output the result as a string with the correct headers, and the browser will happily use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. Ensure your declarations are equally [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) but come later in the stylesheet:

```css
div p strong {color:red!important}
div p strong {color:blue!important}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>lorem <strong>ipsum</strong></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

2. Make your declaration *more* specific:

```css
section div p strong {color:blue!important}
div p strong {color:red!important}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>lorem <strong>ipsum</strong></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

See: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ for some useful tips.

Comment: Technically this is correct, but it would require me to use `!important` after each statement, which I really like to avoid to keep at least my code as clean as I can …

Comment: @Afterlame Yes, well you can't control the mistakes of previous developers. I would clean up the original stylesheet and not add your own into the mix.

Comment: Hm ok, so it is this, or the possibility of my client to break everything by updating the theme. The choice between a rock and a hard place … But thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

Normally with a child theme you would directly edit it. But if you are concerned about getting updates for the child theme, you could also deregister the crappy stylesheet and enqueue your own version from a plugin.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Fix Theme Stylesheets
Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33544364/383847
Description: Save me from these poorly coded marketplace themes
Version:     0.1-alpha
Author:      helgatheviking
Author URI:  http://kathyisawesome.com
 */


function so_33544364_custom_scripts() {
    $theme = get_template();

    if( ! is_admin() && 'your-themes-folder-name' == $theme ){
        // get rid of the child theme's crappy stylesheet
        wp_deregister_style( 'child-style' );
        // optionaly load the parent theme directly instead of importing. can be better for minifying plugins
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        // load your improved stylsheet! style.css in the same folder as this plugin file
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_33544364_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best way to do it I think! One thing I changed is to fire the action with a priority of `30` to load the stylesheets after the woocommerce one.

Comment: I am not sure who to give the correct answer to. You provided me the best solution to my problem, but @Moob answered the question from the headline …

Comment: It's all up to you. I have twice changed my "acepted" answer when a late user gave me a much better (for my project) solution... I can't be sure but @moob looks like have enough rep as to be around for quite a while and probably he may not get mad... HOWEVER, imho, just my opinion, you asked for a css solution and didn't even tag your question with `php` so in this case, it would seem unfair to change the valid answer. Your decision but still my vote up to this answer.

Comment: I won't feel bad if you don't accept it. The other answer obviously answers the question as you asked it. I tried to answer the question you were trying to ask. ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah, that’s it: Moob answered my question, so I won’t change the accept, but you gave me a good solution, so take my up vote and my gratitude. ;)

Comment: @Afterlame - It makes no odds to me who's answer you choose to accept or whether you change your mind at a later date. You should accept the answer that best answers the question posed, but ultimately the best answer is the one that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` is in 99% of cases a lazy way to obtain something that should be reached being more specific; specificity AND positioning are both keys elements, for instance:

```
p.foo { text-align: right; }
```

can be overwritten in this way:

```
body p.foo { text-align: left; }
```

Specificity is very important and it's the right way to go, here how you can calculate it:
[link](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. He knows already about !important. Just read the question before adding an answer.

Comment: Higher specify would not overwrite `!important`, so this would not work for me …

Comment: Considering the specificity is the best way to get rid of the problem, rather than looking for another "higer level of !important".
Mine was a consideration, not a criticism to the question.
Read the answer and consider implications before commenting, thanks.

Comment: @afterflame: you can't indeed, that's why you should consider it from the original .css file. If your question is just "How can override the `!important` statement?" The answer is: "Only `inline` you can".

Comment: @holden I agree with you that I should completely avoid `!important` in my own code if possible, but there seems to be no way to do that without altering the original stylesheet. If I could touch the original css file, I could do it like you suggested, but if my client updates the third party theme, all the `!important` declarations are back and my css is worthless.

Answer (score -2):

ya you will try to using parent div..eg:-

```
.parent_div Child_div ul li{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

this is way to Without using !important.parent div most be ist preroty rather than !important